# CSS Grid in Tailwind creates a grid, put only populates certain cells

Tags: css, next.js, grid, tailwind-css, css-grid

I am using `Tailwindcss` in my `Next.js` app, to display a number of images that come from a `Supabase` database on a grid. However, I am experiencing an issue, where when I inspect the page, the grid appears to be there, but the images are displayed in rows, rather than columns. Here's a screenshot of what I mean.

[image]

The way this is set up is with a component holding the image, which populates a gallery, and the gallery is nested in my index.js. This is what that looks like:

IMAGE

```
<a  href={img.id}  className='group'>
<div  className='aspect-w-3 aspect-h-4 w-full overflow-hidden rounded-md bg-gray-200'>

<Image
alt={img.title}
src={img.imageSrc}
width="200"
height="300"
layout="fill"
objectFit='cover'
className={cn('group-hover:opacity-75 duration-700 ease-in-out',
isLoading? 'grayscale blur-2xl scale-110':'grayscale-0 blur-0 scale-100'
 )}
onLoadingComplete={()  =>  setLoading(false)}
/>

</div>
```

GALLERY

```
<div className="mx-auto max-w-2xl py-16 px-4 sm:py-24 sm:px-6 lg:max-w-7xl">
      <div className="grid grid-cols-1 grid-flow-row-dense gap-y-10 sm:grid-cols-2 gap-x-6 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-4 xl:gap-x-8">
        <div>
          <BlurImage key={img.id} img={img} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

INDEX

```
 <div className="mx-auto">
    {product.map((img)  =>  (
    <Gallery  key={img.id}  img={img}  />
    ))}
    </div>
```

I am looking to display all images on a grid, positioned side by side and wrapping to the next row, which to my understanding should be the default behavior of CSS Grid.

UPDATE: Upon further inspection of the site, I want to update the question. As you can see in the screenshot, the div that holds the grid container has been multiplied 5 times (which correlates with the number of items in the database).

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Not too sure without testing the site, but it does looks like the grid container `div` is multiplied since `Gallery` is being mapped.

Any chance just 1 gallery is needed? In such case, perhaps consider not to `map()` the gallery, instead pass `product` data as props to `gallery` and `map()` the images.

Perhaps something like:

```
<div className="mx-auto">
  <Gallery images={product} />
</div>
```

```
<div className="mx-auto max-w-2xl py-16 px-4 sm:py-24 sm:px-6 lg:max-w-7xl">
  <div className="grid grid-cols-1 grid-flow-row-dense gap-y-10 sm:grid-cols-2 gap-x-6 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-4 xl:gap-x-8">
    {props.images &&
      props.images.map((img) => <BlurImage key={img.id} img={img} />)}
  </div>
</div>
```

**Original**

I tried the posted `grid` container styles in this minimized [test](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-fn7ytq?file=src/App.jsx) and it seems to have no errors.

Any chance the posted code of "GALLERY" could be missing a `map()`? Because it seems that each `Gallery` should probably be given a set of `images` to populate inside the `grid` container, by using `BlurImage`.

If this is the case, perhaps try remove the additional `div` wrapping `BlurImage` so the populate components are placed by the `grid` container.

GALLERY

```
// "images" is a placeholder for a set of images given to Gallery as props

<div className="mx-auto max-w-2xl py-16 px-4 sm:py-24 sm:px-6 lg:max-w-7xl">
  <div className="grid grid-cols-1 grid-flow-row-dense gap-y-10 sm:grid-cols-2 gap-x-6 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-4 xl:gap-x-8">
    {images.map((item) => (
      <BlurImage key={img.id} img={img} />
    ))}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. 
That would make sense, however, I tried your solution (appreciate you taking the time), and my desired result was not achieved. The images are now not visible anymore, on inspection it appears as though the grid div is multiplied by the number of images (it shows as an empty div 5 times).
Which, on further investigation, did happen before as well (I will update the question with this detail). 
Thank you for your time and effort, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @nelakay Not too sure without testing the site, but it does looks like the grid container `div` is the multiplied because you're mapping a set of `Gallery`. Any chance just one gallery is needed? In such case, there might be no need to `map()` it, instead perhaps consider pass the `product` data as props to it so can be mapped as images inside `Gallery`.